# how to use Trunc(mydate) in a cursor loop

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I am new to PL/SQL, and am working on cursor today and got a scenario where I need to get the duplicate transaction type based on the date+amount+cust_id+txn_tpye. Once I get the duplicates I have to use another cursor or just normal loop using the select columns values (date+amount+cust_id+txn_tpye) as a where clause.

Before that I'm just trying to print them if I am getting a value or not, when I tried to print a mydate value getting error. Requesting help from you folks.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

declare 

CURSOR dup_check

IS 

SELECT cust_id,amount,trunc(mydate),transaction_type,COUNT(1)
 FROM table_X WHERE trunc(mydate)>='10-OCT-2015' 
GROUP BY cust_id,amount,trunc(mydate),transaction_type
HAVING COUNT(1)>1 ;

BEGIN

FOR UP_REC IN dup_check

LOOP 

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(UP_REC.cust_id||'  '||UP_REC.amount||UP_REC.trnasaction_type||**trunc(mydate))**;

END LOOP;

END;


**PLS-00302: component 'mydate' must be declared**
```

Answer (score 0):

add alias for trunc(mydate) field as below and put the UP_REC.mydate in your dbms_output

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
declare
CURSOR dup_check
IS
SELECT cust_id,
       amount,
       trunc(mydate) mydate, /* add an alias here */
       transaction_type,
       COUNT(1) 
 FROM table_X WHERE trunc(mydate) >= '10-OCT-2015' 
 GROUP BY cust_id,amount,trunc(mydate),transaction_type HAVING COUNT(1)>1 ;

BEGIN

FOR UP_REC IN dup_check
LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(UP_REC.cust_id||' '||UP_REC.amount||UP_REC.trnasaction_type||UP_REC.mydate));
END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: Hello Narendra , Thanks for the information. Great !! it worked. Simple things make life easier.